# Trouble with LibXSLT install on Windows machine

Tags: php, installation, php-extension

I am on Windows 7 Business and I have installed Apache 2.2.21 and PHP 5.3.5. I want to install Symphony on my local development machine to try it out, but as I try to get it on my system I get the following error:

> Symphony needs an XSLT processor such as LibXSLT or Sablotron to build
>   pages.

So I went on the [PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsl.installation.php) in order to enable such feature where I find this line:

> PHP 5 includes the XSL extension by default and can be enabled by
>   adding the argument `--with-xsl[=DIR]` to your configure line. `DIR` is
>   the `libxslt` installation directory.

but I don't know what configuration line it is referring to. More over scrolling down the page there's a comment regarding Windows systems:

> If you want to activate this extension on Windows, uncomment
>   `";extension=php_xsl.dll"` in your `php.ini` file, and direct it to its
>   respective folder. e.g. `"extension=ext/php_xsl.dll"`

but `";extension=php_xsl.dll"` is not in my php.ini file. So how to I get this extension work?

Answer (score 0):

Its too late and I guess you would have figured it out already!
The fix is pretty simple, actually.

Start up WAMPServer, go to PHP > PHP Extensions and check 'php_xsl'

This effectively unchecks the comment in php.ini and enables the php_xsl.dll
The server will restart and TADA! Symphony is ready for installation.